# What's the best way of telling Kaffeine to play in random order the 15 newest files in a directory in linux?

Tags: linux, bash, script, alias

I want to be able to use kaffeine or another media player to randomly play an arbitrary number of  the newest files in a particular directory. Preferably with as little typing as possible, and I am not opposed to using a script or an alias. I figure there's some way I can use **head** and **ls -1** or some other parameter to create a list that I can pass to kaffeine (mplayer, dragon player, etc) as a parameter. I'm using *bash* on *Ubuntu* Jaunty Jackalope if it makes any difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a function to create the file list:

```
function newest () {
    find . -type f -printf "%T@ %f\n" | sort -n | tail -n ${1:-15} | cut -f 2 -d " " | sort -R
}
```

It defaults to 15 files, but accepts  a parameter for a different number. The last sort puts the list in random order.

For mplayer, you should be able to do:

```
mplayer $(newest 10)
```

or

```
mplayer <(newest 10)
```

Note that mplayer has a `-shuffle` option.